# CSS :not selector being ignored

Tags: html, css

So I have a div with `class='content'` and inside that, another div with attribute `style='background-color:#FF0000'` so my code looks like the following:

```html
<div class='content'>
    Here is some text outside the red background div
    <div style='background-color:#FF0000'>
        Here is some text inside the red background div
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my stylesheet I have the following:

```css
[style^='background'] {
    color:#00FF00
}
```

This works and I get green text inside the red background. However:

```css
:not([style^='background']) {
    color:#00FF00
}
```

This **still** makes the red background text green, along with everything else in the document. I have tried the following:

```css
div:not([style^='background']) {
    color:#00FF00
}
```

```css
.content :not([style^='background']) {
    color:#00FF00
}
```

```css
:not([style]) {
    color:#00FF00
}
```

Yet all of these make the red-background text green, when **clearly** I have the `:not` selector.

However, I have elsewhere:

```css
.content div:not([style^='text-align']) {
    color:#1f1f1f;
}
.content div :not(span[style^='font-size: 150%']) {
    color:#EEE;
}
```

And these work just fine.

So I don't understand why the red background div won't work at all and is selected by the `:not` selector?

Example:

```css
:not(.content) {
    color:#FF0000
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
    Here is some text that shouldn't be red
</div>
```

Comment: any element is *:not(.content)* so you are targetting ALL the element minus one

Answer (score 2):

`color` is an [inherited property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance#Inherited_properties). So if your element has no color set, it inherits the color from the next ancestor element that has a color defined. In your example,

```
:not(.content) { color: #F00; }
```

this also targets the `body` element, so your `div.content` inherits `color: #F00;`.

To avoid this, specify inherited properties on the elements you don't want inheritance on.

```css
.content { color: green; }

:not(.content) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    Here is some text that shouldn't be red
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quirks, tricks, and unexpected results of `:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Description)

> `:not(.foo)` will match anything that isn't `.foo`, *including `<html>` and `<body>`*.

You need to increase specificity to avoid this, e.g. `div:not(.content)`.

In addition:

```css
div:not([style^='background']) {
    /* also targets parent divs */
    color: #00FF00;
}
.content :not([style^='background']) {
    /* You have a space here - this targets _children_ of .content
       that are :not([style^='background']. Is this what you want? */
    color: #00FF00;
}
```

Remember that the "C" in "CSS" stands for *cascading*, and one aspect of that is *inherited styles*. Many styles (such as `color`) affect children of matched elements too, not just the element itself.